# Trying to make this query work in a Lumen project

Tags: php, mysql, sql, eloquent

I'm working on a Lumen project and I'm stumped getting this to work. This is my first project in php using Lumen. I tested the query on Workbench and get the correct result but I have no idea how to get it to work.

```
with top as
(
    select tbl.*, row_number() over (partition by sensor order by timestamp desc) as parted from sometable as tbl
)
select * from top where parted <=3
```

working through the Laravel query builder documentation as well as using other similar questions to get it to work.
This gets me close:

```
$result = Mydb::select(DB::raw("* row_number() over (partition by sensor order by timestamp desc) as parted"))
->get()->where('parted', '<=', 3);
```

But the json is poorly formatted with some added index I don't know where it comes from.

Comment: Try to read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382573/how-do-you-use-the-with-clause-in-mysql

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? CTE requires 8.0 or higher.

Comment: I am using a version 8.0+ I just need the most recent temperature readings from each of my Pi.

Comment: Try reading this post...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54194241/how-to-do-common-table-expressions-in-laravel-eloquent-for-mysql-8